# Camel route - submit job, poll for response

Tags: apache-camel

I am looking for some ideas on how to implement the following pattern with camel route:

1. Client calls web service (originalService) via HTTP rest endpoint.
2. The service takes body of the service and submits it as job to another web service (jobService).  This secondary service returns job id.
3. Using the job id, the originalService polls the jobService for amount of time not exceeding x seconds.  Originalservice will return the result of the the submitted service back to caller. If the job takes longer than x seconds (no response from the jobService) the originalService will send a "timeout" response to the client.

Any idea's on how to implement the "originalService" using camel route?  I don't want to block the thread for x seconds while I am probing the jobService for status of the job.

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches spring to mind.

**1: Procedurally**

Put a loop in your route with a delay and a fixed number of iterations.  Psuedo-Camel:

```
from(myEndpoint)
  to(submitRequest)
  loop(5 times)
    enrich(pollJob, myAggregator)
    choice.when(complete)
      stop
    otherwise
      delay(1000ms)
  endloop
```

`myAggregator` would need to look at the result of the poll operation to determine if the job is complete, extract the result and set an exchange property to indicate success.  If you fall out of the bottom of the loop you've exceeded your timeout.

Here the route makes it fairly obvious what is going on, but it's a little contrived.

**2: Custom Camel component**

You could build your own Camel component to represent your service, which would support a producer for submitting jobs and polling for completion.  You'd do the polling internally within the component so the route would be greatly simplified, e.g.:

```
from(myEndpoint)
  to(myComponent:doRequest?interval=1000ms&attempts=5)
```

The producer within your component can leverage other Camel components if you want to use them to make the REST/SOAP/whatever calls, or you can use CXF/whatever directly if you prefer.

It's up to you how to implement the failure scenario, when you run out of attempts.  An exception would be appropriate, then the Camel error handler would kick in.

Building your own components is straightforward and a powerful way to implement complex behaviour which routes are sometimes not so great at.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion.   I think I'll use the loop approach for now.  If I'll have more time I will explore creating my own component.